# Solr 7,7 Error creating document, but why?

Tags: solr, ascii

I have a newly installed 7,7 Solr.
I can't input my documents. Have you ever encountered & # 8203; ? (without the spaces)
the explanation i found this explanation Unicode Character 'ZERO WIDTH SPACE' (U+200B). 
I get my data by a SQL to Oracle. 'Select from table(xxx)'

can it be that, which are causing my problems?

I get this error:

```
*Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [centralstatus=1,&#8203; 
demovare=0,&#8203; lagerstatus=1,&#8203; nyhed=0,&#8203; 
billedsam=101000847592.JPG,&#8203; pris=499,&#8203; nodeid=360268580,&#8203; 
gruppenavn=Pladedele,&#8203; varenummer=101000847592,&#8203; 
varegruppe=9110,&#8203; produktnodeid=721662042,&#8203; 
prisstreng=499,&#8203; langtnavn=Skærmkant bag Starlet EP70 10/84-11/89 
H,&#8203; billede=101000847592.JPG,&#8203; varetype=0,&#8203; 
kortnavn=Skærmkant bag Starlet EP70 10/84-11/89 H,&#8203; 
langtekst=oracle.sql.CLOB@b2f4e9b,&#8203; nodehovedgruppe=200,&#8203; 
rewriteurl=/bil/autoreservedele/toyota/starlet/1-0/1984/pladedele/skaermkant- 
bag-starlet-ep70-10-84-11-89-h,&#8203; eankode=5705755364180,&#8203; 
hovedgruppenavn=Autoreservedele,&#8203; afhentkunvedlager=0])*
```

i have included a dataimport.properties file

**solrconfig** - new references. everything else i standart

```
 <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="ojdbc5.jar" />
 <lib dir="${solr.install.dir:../../../..}/dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-\d.*\.jar" />
```

**schema**

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> 
<field name="kortnavn" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="langtnavn" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="nodeid" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="produktnodeid" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="varenummer" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="demovare" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="nyhed" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="afhentkunvedlager" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="eankode" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="leveankode" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="varetype" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="styklistebilleder" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="billede" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="billedsam" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="lagerstatus" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="centralstatus" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="nodehovedgruppe" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="hovedgruppenavn" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="varegruppe" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="gruppenavn" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="prisstreng" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="pris" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="foerpris" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="brand" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="filename" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="rewriteurl" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="langtekst" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="korttekst" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="teknisknotat" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="nodesti" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

 <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
 <field name="_root_" type="string" indexed="true" stored="false" docValues="false" /> 
 <field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
```

Comment: You have a uniqueKey that references a field named `ìd` but no field named `id` - and your document doesn't seem to include a value for `id` neither .. Try to see if that could be the issue first.

Comment: <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" /> I didn't get it in the copy paste, but thanks

Comment: So is the field included in the documents you're trying to index? The Solr log should also have a more extensive error message which should tell you why indexing failed.

Comment: I have checked several times if the properties are the same, they are. and i have set  logging for dataimport to ALL,  the warning is the same, and all files are dumbed

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an `id` field in the document you're trying to index, and the `id` field is defined as required. Have you tried to include a dummy id field (i.e. `SELECT 1 AS id, .. ` to see if that helps?

Comment: You are almost right, there is an id, but it is like it dosen't grab it. it doens't take the empty / null fields either

Comment: @MatsLindh you pointed me in the correct direction, you where right i couldn't find the id - because it is case sensitive apparently.